# How to scrape product prices that are regionally specific

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

As an exercise, I am trying to scrape information about washing machines from Lowes. https://www.lowes.com/pl/Washing-machines-Washers-dryers-Appliances/4294857977

To access the price I need to find a **div** with class "product-pricing" and then inside that get the text of a **span**. However, when I inspect the **div** in my browser it is totally different from when I scrape it using beautifulsoup. When I inspect it looks like this:

```
<div class="product-pricing">
<div class="pl-price js-pl-price" tabindex="-1">                 

     <!-- Was Price -->
     <div class="v-spacing-mini">
           <span class="h5 js-price met-product-price art-pl-contractPricing0" data-met-type="was">$499.00</span>
     </div>
     <div class="v-spacing-mini">
           <p class="darkMidGrey art-pl-wasPriceLbl0">was: $749.00</p>

              <small class="green small art-pl-saveThruLbl0">SAVE 33% thru 10/30/2018</small><br>
     </div>

  <!-- Start of Product Family Pricing -->

  <!-- Contractor Pack Messaging -->

  <!-- End of Product Family Pricing -->
  </div>
  <div class="v-spacing-small">
     <a role="link" tabindex="-1" data-toggle="popover" aria-haspopup="true" data-trigger="focus" data-placement="bottom auto" data-content="FREE local delivery applies to any major appliance $396 or more, full-size gas grills $498 or more, patio furniture orders $498 or more, and riding and ZTR mowers $999 or more. Applies to standard deliveries in US only. Purchase threshold calculated before taxes, after applicable discounts, if any. Additional fees may apply." data-original-title="Free Delivery" class="js-truck-delivery"><i class="icon-truck" title="FREE Delivery" aria-label="FREE Delivery."></i> <strong>FREE Delivery</strong></a>
  </div>
</div>
```

But when I scrape I instead see:

```
<div class="product-pricing">
<div class="v-spacing-jumbo clearfix">
  <a aria-haspopup="true" class="js-enter-location" data-content="Since Lowes.com is national in scope, we check inventory at your local store first in an effort to fulfill your order more quickly. You may find product or pricing that differ from that of your local store, but we make every effort to minimize those differences so you can get exactly what you want at the best possible price." data-placement="top auto" data-toggle="popover" data-trigger="focus" role="link" tabindex="-1">
     <p class="h6" id="ada-enter-location"><span>Enter your location</span>
        <i aria-hidden="true" class="icon-info royalBlue"></i>
     </p>
  </a>
  <p class="small-type secondary-text" tabindex="-1">for pricing and availability.</p>
</div>
<form action="#" class="met-zip-container js-store-locator-form" data-modal-open="true" data-zip-in="true" id="store-locator-form">
  <input name="redirectUrl" type="hidden" value="/pl/Washing-machines-Washers-dryers-Appliances/4294857977"/>
  <div class="form-group product-form-group">
     <div class="input-group">
        <input aria-label="Enter your zip code" autocompletetype="find-a-store-search" class="form-control js-list-zip-entry-input met-zip-code" name="searchTerm" placeholder="ZIP Code" role="textbox" tabindex="-1" type="text"/>
        <span class="input-group-btn">
        <button class="btn btn-primary js-list-zip-entry-submit met-zip-submit" data-linkid="get-pricing-and-availability-zip-in-modal-submit" tabindex="-1" type="submit">OK</button>
        </span>
     </div>
     <span class="inline-help">ZIP Code</span>
  </div>
 </form>
</div>
```

I think it has to do with the fact that the website has to use my location to determine the correct price. There seems to be a hidden input where my browser knows my location and tells the website, is there a way for beautiful soup to scrape the price that comes out after it checks my location?

Here is the code I am using:

```
import re
import bs4
from urllib.request import urlopen as uReq
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup as soup

my_url = 'https://www.lowes.com/pl/Washing-machines-Washers-dryers- 
Appliances/4294857977'

uClient = uReq(my_url)

page_html = uClient.read()
uClient.close()

page_soup = soup(page_html, features = "lxml")

containers = page_soup.findAll("div", {"class":"product-wrapper-right"})
for container in containers:
    price = container.findAll("span", {"class":"js-price"})[0].text
```

edit: the specific code the gives me the second html is

```
container.findAll("div", {"class":"product-pricing"})
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not 100% sure this will fix ur issue but using selenium might help since it is an actual browser and will send data that normal browsers send when accessing a website.

A link to an introduction to Selenium: https://medium.freecodecamp.org/better-web-scraping-in-python-with-selenium-beautiful-soup-and-pandas-d6390592e251

Comment: Thank you! Opening the page in selenium first allowed me to get the correct div, and thus the prices!

Comment: Your welcome. I don’t mean to be rude or anything but if this was the answer to the question put my answer as the accepted answer for this stackoverflow question that would be great!

Comment: Sure thing! I'm new to stack overflow, so I didn't know about that. Thanks again!

Comment: No Problem happy I could help.